Relationship between tenor and portfolio performance
I'm analysing the connection between the tenor of secured loan contracts and loan performance, represented by 30DPD@3MOB and 90DPD@12MOB (dummy variables).
I'm using logistic regression, which according to my understanding is the most appropriate model when the dependent variable is dummy.
First analysis: Independent variable is "tenor" (measured in months). The result indicates no significant relationship between tenor and both 30DPD@3MOB and 90DPD@12MOB.
Second analysis: Independent variable is "more_than_60" (dummy variable, being 1 when the tenor is from 60 months and above, 0 otherwise). This time, the result shows that when the tenor of the contract is 60 months or above, there is a much higher chance that the loan is defaulted.
In both analyses, I include the "admission_score", which is already pretty good at capturing the customer's ability to repay debt.
Do the results from the 2 analyses sound contradicting to each other? Any suggestions?
Thanks!
